# how to open a .bundle file

Tags: git, git-bundle

I received `.bundle` file in my gmail. I was told that it was a git bundle file. I tried to open it in sublime and I got a bunch of what seemed to have looked like hex values. It is suppose to be instructions for a code challenge. I have a mac. Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I needed to initialize the Git repository and add `master` to the end of pull as shown below:

```
git init
git pull file.bundle master
```

Answer (score 16):

```
git clone file.bundle targetdir
```

Or

```
git pull /tmp/file.bundle REFNAME
```

Comment: when I try the git clone method I get this result in the terminal:
 
   warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.

Comment: @user3266824 that means it's not a selfcontained bundle. Pull into an existing clone that has the parent ref